# what to do when rule substitution doesn't work?

Tags: replacement, feyncalc

I got an expression

```
expr = 1/SPD[{k1+k2-k},{k1+k2-k}]
```

where `SPD[p, q] is the D-dimensional scalar product of p with q. SPD[p, q] is transformed into Pair[Momentum[p, D],Momentum[q, D]] by FeynCalcInternal.`

then I want apply my defined rule to `expr`

```
rule = { Pair[Momentum[k1, D], Momentum[k2, D]] -> Subscript[s, 12]/2,

         Pair[Momentum[k1, D], Momentum[k, D]] -> (Subscript[s, 12] 
         +Subscript[s, 13] + Subscript[s, 14] - 2 m^2)/2,

         Pair[Momentum[k2, D], Momentum[k, D]] -> (Subscript[s, 12] +   
         Subscript[s, 23] + Subscript[s, 24] - 2 m^2)/2,

         Pair[Momentum[k1, D], Momentum[k1, D]] -> 0,

         Pair[Momentum[k2, D], Momentum[k2, D]] -> 0,

         Pair[Momentum[k, D], Momentum[k, D]] -> 0}
```

However,`expr/.rule` doesn't do the replacement, I tried but still couldn't find where the problem is.

Comment: Have a look at `FullForm` of your `expr`. It probably doesn't contain subexpressions you want to replace. You should change your rules to match with what is in `FullForm`  of FeynCalc expression.

Comment: Thank you @Shadowray,, Why `Expand` doesn't work on `expr`  either?

Comment: `Expand` works only for `Times` an `Power`. If you want to expand FeynCalc scalar products you will need something else. I don't have FeynCalc installed, but you can look for something like `ExpandScalarProduct` from FeynCalc package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already suggested by @Shadowray:

```
rule = {SPD[k1, k2] -> Subscript[s, 12]/2, 
   SPD[k, k1] -> 
    1/2 (-2 m^2 + Subscript[s, 12] + Subscript[s, 13] + Subscript[s, 
       14]), SPD[k, k2] -> 
    1/2 (-2 m^2 + Subscript[s, 12] + Subscript[s, 23] + Subscript[s, 
       24]), SPD[k1, k1] -> 0, SPD[k2, k2] -> 0, SPD[k, k] -> 0};

expr = 1/SPD[k1 + k2 - k, k1 + k2 - k]
ExpandScalarProduct[expr] /. FCI[rule]
```

produces

$\frac{1}{4 m^2-s_{12}-s_{13}-s_{14}-s_{23}-s_{24}}$

Notice that I'm using `FCI`/`FCE` conversion to write `rule` in a more compact way.